# Unable to create 'new job' in jenkins, OK button greyed out

Tags: jenkins

I am trying to create a new job in Jenkins. Even after giving 'item name' and type of project as 'freestyle', the 'OK' button is greyed out as shown in the attached screenshot.

[image: ok_button_greyed_out_jenkins]

I am using :

```
Windows 7 32 bit OS
Jenkins version 1.619
```

Can anyone tell how to solve this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `Can anyone tell how to solve this issue.` - Check permissions!

Comment: @Gluttton I have logged-in with administrator access.

Comment: And did you check the Windows permissions? Did you check that the owner of the Jenkins process is able to create a folder on the machine?

Comment: Did you fix it ?

Answer (score 1):

1. Check if the problem is related to your particular browser configuration.
   Try with addons/plugins disabled, or in another browser.
2. Check the Jenkins logs under the logs folder to see if there's anything meaningful.

Answer (score 0):

As the "People" tab in Jenkins says, it "Includes all known “users”, including login identities which the current security realm can enumerate, as well as people mentioned in commit messages in recorded changelogs."

To ensure that you have been assigned with appropriate role, ask a person with admin or dev rights, to go to Manage Jenkins -> Manage and Assign Roles -> Assign Roles, and then add you as user with appropriate rights.

Answer (score 0):

Easy way to fix this issue

Before :
The OK button is disabled:
[image]

After  :
Choosing any items and then OK will enable:
[image]