# Unable to create 'new job' in jenkins v2.309, OK button disabled

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

I am trying to create a new job in Jenkins (docker) latest version 2.309. Even after giving 'item name' and type of project as 'freestyle', the 'OK' button is disabled as shown in the attached screenshot. I have all permissions in place, moreover I am running Jenkins as admin. I have used docker volumes to store data.

```
docker run -u 1000 --name jenkins_test --restart=on-failure:10 -d -v jenkins_logs:/var/log/jenkins_test -v jenkins_data:/var/jenkins_test -v /dev/urandom:/dev/random -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock -p 9080:8080 jenkins/jenkins
```

This question is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31315970/unable-to-create-new-job-in-jenkins-ok-button-greyed-out), however if you see the screenshot you'll see a symbol ">>" without any message. Also I tried all suggestions provided, no luck. Please help me out.

[image]

Comment: same issue happened to me after i upgrade my jenkins and plugins to v2.303.3 .  were you able to find the solution for this ?

Comment: @chandu, no I chose gitlab CI instead. I was just trying out Jenkins new version, as there were no help as such on this error, I left it there. Please let me know if you manage to solve this.

Comment: created Bug https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-67455 , let see if someone has some solution. may be you can also comment there.

Comment: Thanks, I saw your comments in the bug. I think I may also have the same reverse proxy issue. Anyway not so important for me now as we are adapting gitlab CI.

Answer (score 1):

@Rajib Deka, yes, its was  the issue with reverse proxy configuration in our case.  [image]
for checkjobname., it was injecting java script code, may be mimetype changed in latest jenkins version. it was not happening at least until old versions 2.249.2